# How to use a Date Field for Yesterday orders and YTD orders for customers?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My boss wants to have a report that he reviews that would should him every sales order entered from the day before (yesterday).  With just seeing the snapshot details of the sales orders he also wants a view of the customer's Year-To-Date sales history at our company.

My issue is that I am using the field `T0.[DocDate]` in the `WHERE` clause to only show the day before's sales.  How would I also query up the related `T0.[CardName]` and their YTD history for: `YTD Sales Total`, `YTD Gross Profit`, `YTD GP%`?

Here is the code that I have typed thus far:

```
SELECT  T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date',
        T0.[DocNum] AS 'SO #',
        T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer',        
        ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2) AS 'Sales Total',
        ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2) AS 'GP',
        ROUND(((T0.[DocTotal]-(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit]))/NULLIF(t0.[DocTotal],0)*100),2) AS 'GM%'

FROM    dbo.ORDR T0 

WHERE   CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) = T0.DocDate 

ORDER BY    T0.[DocNum]

FOR BROWSE
```

In the code you'll notice I haven't added in the `SELECT` statement any mention of YTD columns.  When I added the fields it never would work because I have no clue how to query the YTD info.  Is it even possible?  Do I need a Sub-Query?

Any advice on this would be very much obliged!!

Thanks.

I am now trying to use the `UNION ALL` for the code and I feel SOOO CLOSE but the 2 columns I union at the end total **everything** up for the date range of year to date.  How do I get the query to recongize that I want it to find the customer and apply that formula to the related customer.  Not as an overall `SUM`?

Here is the new code:

```
SELECT  T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date',
        T0.[DocNum] AS 'SO #',
        T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer',        
        ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2) AS 'Sales Total',
        ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2) AS 'GP',
        ROUND(((T0.[DocTotal]-(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit]))/NULLIF(t0.[DocTotal],0)*100),2) AS 'GM%',
        NULL,
        NULL

FROM    dbo.ORDR T0 

WHERE   CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) = T0.DocDate 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,SUM(T0.[DocTotal]),SUM(T0.[GrosProfit])

FROM dbo.ORDR T0

WHERE   CAST(GETDATE()-365 AS DATE) >= T0.[DocDate]
```

Comment: `SELECT T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date',
  T0.[DocNum] AS 'SO #',
  T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer',  
  ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2) AS 'Sales Total',
  ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2) AS 'GP',
  ROUND(((T0.[DocTotal]-(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit]))/NULLIF(t0.[DocTotal],0)*100),2) AS 'GM%',
  '',
  ''
  
FROM dbo.ORDR T0 

WHERE CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) = T0.DocDate 

UNION ALL

SELECT '','','','','','',SUM(T0.[DocTotal]),SUM(T0.[GrosProfit])

FROM dbo.ORDR T0

WHERE CAST(GETDATE()-365 AS DATE) >= T0.[DocDate]`

Comment: In response to your edits, add a `GROUP BY cardname` clause to the bottom part of your `UNION ALL`

Comment: The only issue is after the initial 45 sales orders from prior day, the next 600 rows have data for the `UNION` columns at the end but the first 6 columns up to it are `NULL` and there isn't 45 more rows but 600 more rows after the prior days sales orders.

Comment: probably meaning you have 600 customers, which you are not showing in the `select` part of the second half of the `union`. I think what you are looking for is a `JOIN`. See the edits to my answer.

Comment: @SAm I got this message `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'CardName'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'No. of Orders'.`

Comment: I fixed the order issue.  But I still get this error message `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
Invalid column name 'CardName'`

Comment: yea there was no space between `No.` and `of` in the subquery. Fixed

Comment: What about the issue with `ON T0.CardName = T1.CardName` it is showing that as the only error in the query.

Comment: Because in the subquery, CardName is aliased `AS 'Customer'`. Either change the alias or change the `join` conditions to `T0.CardName = T1.Customer`

Comment: @SAM I altered the `ON` to say `ON T0.CardName = T1.Customer` and it worked!!!!!!!!  That is awesome!!!!!  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: @Sam one more question, I need the YTD GM% if possible.  I noticed on your code you had `---` on the line in the subset.  When I tried to add it back in, the errors told me that all of the `dbo.`'s were not contained in either an aggregate function or GROUP By clause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85425/discussion-between-sam-cd-and-ktate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them side by side, you can use a join:

```
SELECT  T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date',
        T0.[DocNum] AS 'SO #',
        T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer',        
        ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2) AS 'Sales Total',
        ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2) AS 'GP',
        ROUND(((T0.[DocTotal]-(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit]))/NULLIF(t0.[DocTotal],0)*100),2) AS 'GM%',
    T1.[Sales Total][Sales Total YTD],
    T1.GP [GP YTD],
    T1.[No. of Orders][Orders YTD]


FROM    dbo.ORDR T0 
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    count(T0.[DocNum]) AS 'No. of Orders',
    T0.[CardName] as 'Customer',        
    sum(ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2)) AS 'Sales Total',
    sum(ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2)) AS 'GP'
    ROUND(((sum(T0.[DocTotal])-(sum(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit])))/NULLIF(t0.sum([DocTotal]),0)*100),2) AS 'GM%'
FROM dbo.ORDR T0 
WHERE T0.DocDate between CAST(dateadd(yy,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
and CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
group by t0.cardname) T1
on T0.CardName = T1.Customer    
WHERE   CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) = T0.DocDate 

ORDER BY    T0.[DocNum]
```

Comment: Copied most of this from @vkp just added the partition and deleted the group by

Comment: the thing I am noticing too my boss doesn't want to see is the `between` data.  He wants to see customer xyz's order from yesterday and then from a year ago to today what they have done in sales.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cast(min(T0.[DocDate]) as date) AS 'Start Date',
    cast(max(T0.[DocDate]) as date) AS 'End Date',
    count(T0.[DocNum]) AS 'No.of Orders',
    T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer',        
    sum(ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2)) AS 'Sales Total',
    sum(ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2)) AS 'GP'
    -- ROUND(((T0.[DocTotal]-(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit]))/NULLIF(t0.[DocTotal],0)*100),2) AS 'GM%'
FROM dbo.ORDR T0 
WHERE T0.DocDate between CAST(dateadd(yy,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
and CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
group by t0.cardname
```

Try this for YTD sales.

Edit:

```
SELECT  T0.[DocDate] AS 'Date',
T0.[DocNum] AS 'SO #',
T0.[CardName] AS 'Customer', 
ROUND(T0.[DocTotal],2) AS 'Sales Total',
ROUND(T0.[GrosProfit],2) AS 'GP', 
ROUND(((T0.[DocTotal]-(t0.[DocTotal]-t0.[GrosProfit]))/NULLIF(t0.[DocTotal],0)‌​*100),2) AS 'GM%', 
NULL as Total, NULL as Total_Gross_Profit  -- '', '' 
FROM dbo.ORDR T0
WHERE CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE) = T0.DocDate
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL --'','','','','','',
SUM(T0.[DocTotal]),
SUM(T0.[GrosProfit]) 
FROM dbo.ORDR T0
WHERE CAST(GETDATE()-365 AS DATE) >= T0.[DocDate]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! The issue with modyifying the query to your advice is I see all the Sales Orders between that date range.  I want to see the data as such:  `| Date | SO # | Customer | Total | GP | YTD Tot |` the issue is when that Year-To-Date comes into play.  Should I use a `UNION`?

Comment: You can use `OVER (PARTITION BY cardname)` instead of `GROUP BY`

Comment: @vkp and @Sam I changed up my code and am getting the following messge: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` See my altered code above.  Thanks!

Comment: @KTate you are trying to union `''` which is varchar to a numeric field. Change them to `NULL` or 0, except for 3rd ([cardname]) and possibly 2nd, depending on what data type you have [DocNum] stored as

Comment: @KTate..when you are using `union` it is better to use `null` instead of empty strings `''`. Modified your code accordingly

Comment: @SAM I changed them to `NULL`.  See code: `SELECT NULL,NULL,'',NULL,NULL,NULL,SUM(T0.[DocTotal]),SUM(T0.[GrosProfit])` but i am still getting the error message.  I haven't altered anything about the `DocNum` so I assume it is stored as a numeric value.

Comment: @KTate what about the `''`'s in the top part of your union?

Comment: @Sam I literally changed them as you said that lol.  Didn't even notice.  I added more detail information above in my initial question for this issue.  Does that help anymore?